# Issue with twitter Profile image using Titanium

Tags: twitter, titanium-mobile

I am newbie to titanium, I am learning JSon Parsing with titanium. I am accessing tweets for a specific screen name along with his/her profile picture. It is working well as concern to tweets but not showing the profile picture of that tweet.

My Tweet.js file is :

```
 // Create variable "win" to refer to current window
 var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
 // Function loadTweets()
 function loadTweets()
 {
// Empty array "rowData" for our tableview
var rowData = [];
var avatar;
// Create our HTTP Client and name it "loader"
var loader = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
// Sets the HTTP request method, and the URL to get data from
loader.open("GET","http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=SenchaTouch");
// Runs the function when the data is ready for us to process
loader.onload = function() 
{
    var tweets = eval('('+this.responseText+')');
    alert(tweets);
    for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++)
    {
        var tweet = tweets[i].text; // The tweet message
        var user = tweets[i].user.screen_name; // The screen name of the user
        avatar = tweets[i].user.profile_image_url; // The profile image
        // Create a row and set its height to auto
        var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({height:'auto'});

        // Create the view that will contain the text and avatar
        var post_view = Titanium.UI.createView({
            height:'auto', 
            layout:'vertical',
            top:5,
            right:5,
            bottom:5,
            left:5
        });
        // Create image view to hold profile pic
        var av_image = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
            url:'KS_nav_ui.png', // the image for the image view
            top:0,
            left:0,
            height:48,
            width:48
        });
        post_view.add(av_image);
        // Create the label to hold the screen name
        var user_lbl = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
            text:user,
            left:54,
            width:120,
            top:-48,
            bottom:2,
            height:16,
            textAlign:'left',
            color:'#444444',
            font:{fontFamily:'Trebuchet MS',fontSize:14,fontWeight:'bold'}
        });
        post_view.add(user_lbl);
        // Create the label to hold the tweet message
        var tweet_lbl = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
            text:tweet,
            left:54,
            top:0,
            bottom:2,
            height:'auto',
            width:236,
            textAlign:'left',
            font:{fontSize:14}
        });
        post_view.add(tweet_lbl);
        // Add the post view to the row
        row.add(post_view);
        // Give each row a class name
        row.className = "item"+i;
        // Add row to the rowData array
        rowData[i] = row;
    }
    // Create the table view and set its data source to "rowData" array
    var tableView = Titanium.UI.createTableView({data:rowData});
    //Add the table view to the window
    win.add(tableView);
};
// Send the HTTP request
loader.send();
   }
   loadTweets();
```

// Can  any find out the flaw  ?? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanking in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last found it .. The problem was in code. I just use url property in the image view instead of image property. Replacing the image property with that of url has done the trick.

```
  url: avatar, // It should not be used .. It is not working 
  image: avatar, // It is working very well..
```